# How to connect a condenser microphone directly to a PC (without a mixer)

Tags: microphone, phantom, behringer, pre-amp

I have a condenser microphone Rode NT2 and I connected it to a PC in this way:

1. The Rode NT2 is connected via XLR to a Behringer Phantom power generator.
2. The phantom power generator is connected to a cable that convert xlr to a mini jack
3. The mini jack is connected to the PC.

The problem here is that the volume of the mic is very low, as I don't have any gain that I can control. I would probably need some sort of pre-amp.

What kind of pre-amp in that case? Is there any impedance to take into account here?

Answer (score 2):

Just get a basic Behringer USB preamp interface that supports Phantom power. Then there's a direct connection from the microphone through the preamp into the computer. Job done. Impedance isn't a problem for you. Just get the interface, plug it in and then manage the preamp gain on the interface.